# Can't make vsftpd on kubernetes (minikube) with load balancer AND ssl work

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, vsftpd, ftps, minikube

### CONTEXT

School project : to host several services on a kubernetes node minikube including a ftps server on port 21 using a load balancer. School ask us to make our own images based on Alpine.

### What I did so far

I setup metallb as loadbalancer.

I build an image in which I setup vsftpd and generate certificate and keys :

```
openssl req -x509 -subj "/C=FR/ST=PARIS/L=Paris/O=42_Corp/OU=myname/CN=mywebsite" -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/vsftpd.crt
```

side note : I use supervisor in order to run telegraf in the same container to get a dashboard.

I deploy this image with this yml:

```
metadata:
  name: ftps
spec:
  serviceName: "ftps"
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ftps
  replicas: 2 # tells deployment to run 2 pods matching the template
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ftps
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ftps
        image: ft_service/ftps
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        volumeMounts:
        - name: ftps-data
          mountPath: /mnt/ftps_data
      volumes:
      - name: ftps-data
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: ftps
  name: ftps
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - name: port-20
    port: 20
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 20
  - name: port-21
    port: 21
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 21
  selector:
    app: ftps
```

Then I have a conf file for vsftp which contain this :

```
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
listen=YES


rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/vsftpd.crt
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.key
ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
require_ssl_reuse=NO
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
seccomp_sandbox=NO
```

(the last "seccomp_sandbox=NO" seemed to resolve some issues I had a the begining)

### Which gives me...

Once I deploy everything, I get my pods :

```
default          pod/ftps-1                             1/1     Running   0          7m55s
```

I get my service:

```
default       service/ftps         LoadBalancer   10.104.132.127   192.168.1.241   20:31268/TCP,21:31581/TCP   8m43s
```

Then when I run `minikube service ftps --url`,
I get
`http://172.17.0.2:31268`
`http://172.17.0.2:31581`

### WHERE I HAVE AN ISSUE

I use lftp (I tried few other with pretty much the same result, so I ruled out the client issue... but I pretty new to the whole ftp thing so... I let you judge)

## 1. Using lftp with ftps://

`lftp -u user,password ftps://172.17.0.2 -p 31581`
then `ls`

`ls: Fatal error: gnutls_handshake: An unexpected TLS packet was received`

Here is the very long version using debug (I truncated many "GNUTLS: ASSERT: extensions.c[_gnutls_get_extension]:65" lines because of post limitations) :

```
lftp ftp42@172.17.0.2:~> debug 99999999
lftp ftp42@172.17.0.2:~> ls
FileCopy(0x563eb3eed780) enters state INITIAL
FileCopy(0x563eb3eed780) enters state DO_COPY
---- dns cache hit
---- attempt number 1 (max_retries=1000)
---- Connecting to 172.17.0.2 (172.17.0.2) port 31581
GNUTLS: ASSERT: extensions.c[_gnutls_get_extension]:65
GNUTLS: ASSERT: extensions.c[_gnutls_get_extension]:65
GNUTLS: ASSERT: extensions.c[_gnutls_get_extension]:65
GNUTLS: ASSERT: extensions.c[_gnutls_get_extension]:65
GNUTLS: ASSERT: extensions.c[_gnutls_get_extension]:65
GNUTLS: ASSERT: extensions.c[_gnutls_get_extension]:65

[...]

GNUTLS: ASSERT: extensions.c[_gnutls_get_extension]:65
GNUTLS: ASSERT: extensions.c[_gnutls_get_extension]:65
GNUTLS: ASSERT: extensions.c[_gnutls_get_extension]:65
GNUTLS: ASSERT: extensions.c[_gnutls_get_extension]:65
GNUTLS: ASSERT: common.c[x509_read_value]:698
GNUTLS: ASSERT: common.c[x509_read_value]:698
GNUTLS: ASSERT: extensions.c[_gnutls_get_extension]:65
GNUTLS: ASSERT: extensions.c[_gnutls_get_extension]:65
GNUTLS: REC[0x563eb42050a0]: Allocating epoch #0
GNUTLS: ASSERT: constate.c[_gnutls_epoch_get]:600
GNUTLS: REC[0x563eb42050a0]: Allocating epoch #1
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Adv. version: 3.3
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (C0.2C)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_CAMELLIA_256_GCM_SHA384 (C0.87)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_CHACHA20_POLY1305 (CC.A9)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_AES_256_CCM (C0.AD)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA1 (C0.0A)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (C0.2B)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_CAMELLIA_128_GCM_SHA256 (C0.86)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_AES_128_CCM (C0.AC)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA1 (C0.09)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA1 (C0.08)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (C0.30)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_ECDHE_RSA_CAMELLIA_256_GCM_SHA384 (C0.8B)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_ECDHE_RSA_CHACHA20_POLY1305 (CC.A8)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA1 (C0.14)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (C0.2F)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_ECDHE_RSA_CAMELLIA_128_GCM_SHA256 (C0.8A)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA1 (C0.13)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_ECDHE_RSA_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA1 (C0.12)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (00.9D)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_RSA_CAMELLIA_256_GCM_SHA384 (C0.7B)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_RSA_AES_256_CCM (C0.9D)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA1 (00.35)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_RSA_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA1 (00.84)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (00.9C)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_RSA_CAMELLIA_128_GCM_SHA256 (C0.7A)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_RSA_AES_128_CCM (C0.9C)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_RSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA1 (00.2F)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_RSA_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA1 (00.41)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_RSA_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA1 (00.0A)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_DHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (00.9F)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_DHE_RSA_CAMELLIA_256_GCM_SHA384 (C0.7D)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_DHE_RSA_CHACHA20_POLY1305 (CC.AA)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_DHE_RSA_AES_256_CCM (C0.9F)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_DHE_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA1 (00.39)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_DHE_RSA_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA1 (00.88)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_DHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (00.9E)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_DHE_RSA_CAMELLIA_128_GCM_SHA256 (C0.7C)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_DHE_RSA_AES_128_CCM (C0.9E)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_DHE_RSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA1 (00.33)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_DHE_RSA_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA1 (00.45)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_DHE_RSA_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA1 (00.16)
GNUTLS: EXT[0x563eb42050a0]: Sending extension Extended Master Secret (0 bytes)
GNUTLS: EXT[0x563eb42050a0]: Sending extension Encrypt-then-MAC (0 bytes)
GNUTLS: EXT[0x563eb42050a0]: Sending extension OCSP Status Request (5 bytes)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: sent server name: '172.17.0.2'
GNUTLS: EXT[0x563eb42050a0]: Sending extension Server Name Indication (15 bytes)
GNUTLS: EXT[0x563eb42050a0]: Sending extension Safe Renegotiation (1 bytes)
GNUTLS: EXT[0x563eb42050a0]: Sending extension Session Ticket (0 bytes)
GNUTLS: EXT[0x563eb42050a0]: Sending extension Supported curves (12 bytes)
GNUTLS: EXT[0x563eb42050a0]: Sending extension Supported ECC Point Formats (2 bytes)
GNUTLS: EXT[0x563eb42050a0]: sent signature algo (4.1) RSA-SHA256
GNUTLS: EXT[0x563eb42050a0]: sent signature algo (4.3) ECDSA-SHA256
GNUTLS: EXT[0x563eb42050a0]: sent signature algo (5.1) RSA-SHA384
GNUTLS: EXT[0x563eb42050a0]: sent signature algo (5.3) ECDSA-SHA384
GNUTLS: EXT[0x563eb42050a0]: sent signature algo (6.1) RSA-SHA512
GNUTLS: EXT[0x563eb42050a0]: sent signature algo (6.3) ECDSA-SHA512
GNUTLS: EXT[0x563eb42050a0]: sent signature algo (3.1) RSA-SHA224
GNUTLS: EXT[0x563eb42050a0]: sent signature algo (3.3) ECDSA-SHA224
GNUTLS: EXT[0x563eb42050a0]: sent signature algo (2.1) RSA-SHA1
GNUTLS: EXT[0x563eb42050a0]: sent signature algo (2.3) ECDSA-SHA1
GNUTLS: EXT[0x563eb42050a0]: Sending extension Signature Algorithms (22 bytes)
GNUTLS: HSK[0x563eb42050a0]: CLIENT HELLO was queued [220 bytes]
GNUTLS: REC[0x563eb42050a0]: Preparing Packet Handshake(22) with length: 220 and min pad: 0
GNUTLS: ENC[0x563eb42050a0]: cipher: NULL, MAC: MAC-NULL, Epoch: 0
GNUTLS: REC[0x563eb42050a0]: Sent Packet[1] Handshake(22) in epoch 0 and length: 225
GNUTLS: ASSERT: buffers.c[get_last_packet]:1160
GNUTLS: ASSERT: buffers.c[_gnutls_io_read_buffered]:587
GNUTLS: ASSERT: buffers.c[get_last_packet]:1160
GNUTLS: ASSERT: buffers.c[_gnutls_io_read_buffered]:587
GNUTLS: ASSERT: buffers.c[get_last_packet]:1160
GNUTLS: REC[0x563eb42050a0]: SSL 48.48 Unknown Packet packet received. Epoch 0, length: 8271
GNUTLS: ASSERT: record.c[check_recv_type]:580
GNUTLS: Received record packet of unknown type 53
GNUTLS: ASSERT: record.c[recv_headers]:1093
GNUTLS: ASSERT: record.c[_gnutls_recv_in_buffers]:1175
GNUTLS: ASSERT: buffers.c[_gnutls_handshake_io_recv_int]:1415
GNUTLS: ASSERT: handshake.c[_gnutls_recv_handshake]:1474
GNUTLS: ASSERT: handshake.c[handshake_client]:2841
**** gnutls_handshake: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
GNUTLS: REC[0x563eb42050a0]: Start of epoch cleanup
GNUTLS: REC[0x563eb42050a0]: End of epoch cleanup
GNUTLS: REC[0x563eb42050a0]: Epoch #0 freed
GNUTLS: REC[0x563eb42050a0]: Epoch #1 freed
---- Closing control socket
ls: Fatal error: gnutls_handshake: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
lftp ftp42@172.17.0.2:~> exit
```

## 2. Using lftp with ftp://

If I remove the s from ftp in the lftp command above, I get :

```
➜  repo git:(master) ✗ lftp -u user,password ftp://172.17.0.2 -p 31581
lftp ftp42@172.17.0.2:~> set ssl:verify-certificate false
lftp ftp42@172.17.0.2:~> ls
Interrupt
lftp ftp42@172.17.0.2:/> debug 9
lftp ftp42@172.17.0.2:/> ls
---- Connecting to 172.17.0.2 (172.17.0.2) port 31581
<--- 220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)
---> FEAT
<--- 211-Features:
<---  AUTH TLS
<---  EPRT
<---  EPSV
<---  MDTM
<---  PASV
<---  PBSZ
<---  PROT
<---  REST STREAM
<---  SIZE
<---  TVFS
<---  UTF8
<--- 211 End
---> AUTH TLS
<--- 234 Proceed with negotiation.
---> OPTS UTF8 ON
Certificate: C=FR,ST=PARIS,L=Paris,O=42_Corp,OU=user,CN=email
 Issued by: C=FR,ST=PARIS,L=Paris,O=42_Corp,OU=user,CN=email
WARNING: Certificate verification: Not trusted (28:51:50:4B:83:40:96:E7:2C:9A:1E:9B:38:C5:25:46:B4:CC:4C:24)
WARNING: Certificate verification: certificate common name doesn't match requested host name ‘172.17.0.2’ (28:51:50:4B:83:40:96:E7:2C:9A:1E:9B:38:C5:25:46:B4:CC:4C:24)
<--- 200 Always in UTF8 mode.
---> USER ftp42
<--- 331 Please specify the password.
---> PASS 42
<--- 230 Login successful.
---> PBSZ 0
<--- 200 PBSZ set to 0.
---> PROT P
<--- 200 PROT now Private.
---> PASV
<--- 227 Entering Passive Mode (172,18,0,6,194,222).
---- Connecting data socket to (172.18.0.6) port 49886
Interrupt
---> LIST
---> ABOR
---- Closing aborted data socket
lftp ftp42@172.17.0.2:/>
<--- 425 Failed to establish connection.
<--- 225 No transfer to ABOR.
lftp ftp42@172.17.0.2:/>
```

### TO SUM UP

I guess my issue is in the ssl configuration, but where ?... What am I missing ?
Thanks for reading this hidiously long post :)

Comment: Did you try to run this image as a simple docker container first ? I would advise you to make things as simple as possible in the beginning. So instead of setting up the whole set of: Statefulset, setting MetalLB and exposing your Pods via LoadBalancer Service I would rather try to run it first as a single Pod to test the image. It will allow you to rule out any factors related with with potential misconfiguration of any part of your kubernetes environment. Once you try the simplest scenario and you are sure it works you may start to to make things more complex.

Comment: You can start from a really simple Pod based on `ft_service/ftps` image and second Pod with `lftp` client installed. You don't even have to build any special image. Just run some ubuntu/debian based image and install in it your ftp client of choice. Try to connect directly to your `vsftpd` pod using it's IP or expose it as a simple `ClusterIP` Service within your cluster and try to connect to the server using Service name. If nothing changes and you still have the same error, you'll be 100% sure the issue is related with nothing else but `vsftpd`/`ssl`-related configuration.

Answer (score 0):

ftps always requires additional ports(passive mode), as you should see in lftp logs, it fails at this point. I solved it by adding ports to ftps k8s service and set particular additional 2 ports in config of vsftpd.